# Haskell: problems fully defining factorial in Continuation Passing Style

Tags: haskell, continuations, factorial

I've been trying to understad Functional Programming, Haskell and Continuation Passing Style in one big blob and my structured/OOP background is giving me a hard time.

According to [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Continuation) I understand the following should be a correct definition of factorial in CPS-style:

```
factorial n = fact n id where id = \x -> x
    fact 0 cont = cont n
    fact (n+1) cont = fact n * (n + 1)
```

but I'm not sure about the "* (n + 1)" part at the end - is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite correct (and doesn't compile for me); the value `n+1` is right but it isn't used in quite the correct way.  Maybe you meant to use an operator section?

```
factorial n' = fact n' id
 where
  id = \x -> x
  fact 0 cont = cont 1
  fact (n+1) cont = fact n (cont . (* (n+1)))
```

This is identical to (but more obtuse than) the following

```
factorial n' = fact n' id
 where
  id = \x -> x
  fact 0 cont = cont 1
  fact (n+1) cont = fact n (\ret -> cont (ret * (n+1)) )
```

There are a few things I would change here.  First, `id` is a standard function so you don't need to redefine it.  Secondly, these examples use "n+k patterns", which IIRC are no longer available by default in GHC.  Instead of an "n+k pattern", you can use a normal pattern variable.  Note that I used `1` for the base case; this is simpler to reason about if you're counting down from `n`, and the continuation function should be applied at each step within the computation (you'd dropped it from the induction step).  With these in mind, you can write

```
factorial n' = fact n' id
 where
  fact 0 cont = cont 1
  fact n cont = fact (n-1) (cont . (* n))
```

which I would consider more or less idiomatic.

Edit: I personally don't like n+k patterns, but I thought I'd take a bit of time to explain them.  I find it easier to follow if you think of mathematical induction with a base case and an induction step.  The base case is `fact 0 ...`.  You then define the other values by proceeding from the base step: "for any `fact n k`, determine `fact (n+1) k` by this relation."  This is different from how I think of normal pattern variables, that is top-down instead of bottom-up as here, but I think it explains the motivation and why some people like the style.

The reason I don't like n+k patterns is simply because I find the definitions more cluttered, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you John - ironically I had just found The Evolution of a Haskell Programmer at http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html, which also suggests "n+k" patterns are a bad idea.

Comment: Haskell 2010 has removed the (n + k) pattern syntax. http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellli2.html#x3-5000

Comment: The `n` in your definitions of `fact` shadows the `n` in `factorial n`, which is bad for clarity.  This is also true of the original question.

Comment: @Nefrubyr - thanks very much; I've edited these to remove the shadowing.